# SQL query optimization (CTE + range function) in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I'm wondering whether such query could be potentially optimized.
I've hugely simplified it, and you see the core of it.

```
with Rec (Id,Name,ParentId)
as
(
    select Id,Name,ParentId from Departments where ParentId is null
    union all
    select d.Id, d.Name, d.ParentId from Departments d join Rec r on 
    (d.ParentId=r.Id)
)
select q.* from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r.Id DESC) AS [ROW_NUMBER], r.* from Rec r
) as q
where q.[ROW_NUMBER] between 100 and 200
```

What it does is hierarchically query the desendent departments and then do a ranging upon it.

I'm ending up with a huge execution plan and wondering if it can be done in a different manner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I quess it could be a bit better given the following assumptions:

1. You have proper index by ParentId
2. You retrieve a lot of data (most of the columns) from the table

What can be done: in order to reduce load on io subsystem we can first compose a list of Id's, page them (i.e. filter by RowNumber) and only after that include all other columns. This will effectively result in working with index by ParentId which should be a lot faster given the above two assumptions.

So here's my proposition 'in person' so to say:

```
with Rec (Id,ParentId)
as
(
    select Id,ParentId from Departments where ParentId is null
    union all
    select d.Id, d.ParentId from Departments d join Rec r on 
    (d.ParentId=r.Id)
),
Paged 
as
(
    select * from (
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r.Id DESC) AS [ROW_NUMBER], r.* from Rec r
    ) as q
    where q.[ROW_NUMBER] between 100 and 200
)
select * 
from 
    Paged
    inner join Departments d on d.Id = Paged.Id
```

Comment: Alex, thanks for helping. I already have my ParentId indexed, and your option produces 0.21 subtree cost whereas mine is 0.17.

Comment: It happens (that proposed changes don't help).
I'm just wondering: did you compared the cost of subtree for this 'simplified case' or for original (complicated, real-world) query? I guess the results can differ significantly.